# Getting error while executing bcp in UNIX box

Tags: linux, perl, bcp

Currently I am working on executing Perl script in Unix box. The Perl script internally uses BCP command for for fetching the data from MS-SQL DB. The same perl script is properly running in Windows. But when I am executing it into Unix (using Putty). It is showing following error message on console.

```
sh: bcp: command not found
```

Below is my sql command in perl script.

```
"bcp \"select drive_id, ilf, xcoord, ycoord 
from $mdtdb\.dbo\.$mdtcentraldtdtable a where 
drive_id = $driveid and not exists 
(select 'x' from $mdtdb\.dbo\.$mdtcentralaudittable b where 
a.drive_id = b.drive_id and a.ilf = b.ilf)\"
 queryout $tempdatafile -o $bcpoutfile -S $mdtsvr -q -c -t , 
 -U $user1 -P $pw1";
```

I am successfully able to connect with the DB.

I need your help to resolve above bcp issue.

Comment: `bcp` is a MS SQLServer utility. I don't believe it exists on anything else than Windows.

Answer (score 2):

On unix, there is a bcp tool for sybase clients. It works only for Sybase Products.

There is an open-source replacement for bcp that works with MSSQL server: [freebcp](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/usefreetds.htm) But the freetds library is a bit difficult to configure, and (being a reverse engineering effort by volunteers)  it works only with relatively simple datatypes.

To install it on ubuntu/debian based linux machines, run this

> apt-cache search freetds

```
freetds-common - configuration files for FreeTDS SQL client libraries
freetds-dev - MS SQL and Sybase client library (static libs and headers)
libct4 - libraries for connecting to MS SQL and Sybase SQL servers
libdbd-freetds - Freetds database server driver for libdbi
libsybdb5 - libraries for connecting to MS SQL and Sybase SQL servers
tdsodbc - ODBC driver for connecting to MS SQL and Sybase SQL servers
freetds-bin - FreeTDS command-line utilities
libaprutil1-dbd-freetds - Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - FreeTDS Driver
sqsh - commandline SQL client for MS SQL and Sybase servers
libqt4-sql-tds - Qt 4 FreeTDS database driver
```

This command is optional:

> apt-file list freetds-bin

```
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/bsqldb
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/bsqlodbc
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/datacopy
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/defncopy
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/fisql
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/freebcp
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/osql
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/tdspool
freetds-bin: /usr/bin/tsql
```

These commands install most of what you need

```
apt-get install freetds-bin 
apt-get install freetds-dev
```

You must then enter your connection data into configfile

```
/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

[OurMSSQLServer]

    host = 1xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

Maybe something else in this configfile has to be changed. This I don't remember right now.

From here on you are on your own. Please read the freetds docs: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/

The freetds software is up-to-date (actively developed). But the dev team is very small I think.

You can also compile freetds from source, but that may take more effort.

Comment: If possible could you please let me know the steps for configuring freebcp on Unix machine. Or give me any reference URL.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very clear: the bcp command is not found in your $PATH and therefore it fails, but the real issue is that bcp is a MS SQL server utility and you won't find it on UNIX

Comment: Do you know any alternative for bcp in UNIX. If it is freebcp, please let me know the configuration steps for that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get programmatic access to an MSSQL database from Perl on unix by using [DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) ‌→ [DBD::ODBC](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aODBC) ‌→ [Easysoft SQL Server ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/)

Comment: But I think Easysoft driver is not for free. We've to purchase it 1st. But, in my current application I've to implement it by using freetds only.

Comment: You started by using MSSQL, which is pay-for software. If you have the money to buy MSSQL, then how come you don't have money to buy a connector? If you don't want to pay for the software, then there is a high-quality free database available: PostgreSQL.

Comment: You might be able to get db access using the sybase dbd driver from perl or python.